# How is it possible to encode """ (triple quotes) into a raw string?

Tags: python, rawstring

How do I encode `"""` in a raw python string?

The following does not seem to work:

```
string = r"""\"\"\""""
```

since when trying to match `"""` with a regular expression, I have to double-escape the character `"`:
**Returns an empty list:**

```
string = r"""\"\"\""""
regEx = re.compile(r"""
        (\"\"\")
""", re.S|re.X)
result = re.findall(regEx, string)
```

in this case result is an empty list.
This same regular expression returns `['"""']` when I load a string with `"""` from file content.

**Returns double-escaped quotations:**

```
string = r"""\"\"\""""
regEx = re.compile(r"""
        (\\"\\"\\")
""", re.S|re.X)
result = re.findall(regEx, string)
```

now result is equal to `['\\"\\"\\"']`.
It want it to be equal to `['"""']`.

Comment: `string = r"""\"\"\""""` - why is *this* string a raw string? It makes sense to use raw strings for regexes, but if you want a string to represent text, raw strings are rarely useful.

Comment: @user2357112: It's for unit testing. I find it much easier to read if the expected value is not one gigantic line with `\n` and `\t` all over the place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, there are three options:

1. Don't use the `r` prefix. That's just a convenience to avoid excessive use of double-backslashes in regexes. It isn't required.
2. Use `r'…'`, inside which the `"` character isn't special.
3. Mix and match `r"…"` and `''`:, e.g. `pattern = '"""' + r"\s*\d\d-'\d\d'-\d\d\s*" + '"""'`

In this instance, you can do both 1 and 2: single quotes and no `r` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to just do `'"""'`.

Comment: @DudeOnRock This answer suggests not using a raw string, but to use `'str'` (different quotes).